# How to install J2ME on Nokia 1200?

Tags: java, java-me

I want to ask wether it's possible to develop a J2ME application for Nokia 1200 phone and then install the application as well as J2ME/Java runtime because it seems that Nokia 1200 doesn't include J2ME/Java runtime : (http://www.mobile88.com/cellphone/Nokia/Nokia-1200/specification.asp) .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Nokia 1200 has the series 30 operating system, and lacks J2ME support. If you want J2ME, you need to go to a series 40 device (like the 3120 classic) or series 60 (E series, N series, etc.)

You can check the features of programmable phones at http://www.forum.nokia.com/devices/matrix_all_1.html

Answer (score 0):

You cant install j2me

Comment: Series 40 comes with J2ME built in